# C++ Aggregation with Navigation from Child to Parent

Tags: c++, aggregation

How would I implement an aggregation relationship with the possibility to navigate from a child object to its parent object?

Do I need to use forward declaration?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/103-aggregation/

Comment: This is exceedingly vague!

Comment: You need JQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do.

```
struct Node;

struct Aggregator {
    Node* parent;

    Node aggregated1, aggregated2;
};

struct Node {
    Aggregator* aggregated_by;
};
```

Though with nested types you might be able to dodge it, or if the parent has the same type:

```
struct Node {
    Node* parent;

    Node aggregated1, aggregated2;
};
```